# Having trouble understanding interface/struct relationship

Tags: struct, go

I am having difficulty understanding the relationship between interfaces and structs in go. I have declared an interface called `Datatype` as follows:

```
package main

type Datatype interface {
    Unmarshal(record []string) error
    String() string
}
```

I have also created several structs that implement this interface. Here is one simple example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/validator.v2"
    "reflect"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

type User struct {
    Username      string `validate:"nonzero"`
    UserId        string `validate:"nonzero"`
    GivenName     string `validate:"nonzero"`
    FamilyName    string `validate:"nonzero"`
    Email         string `validate:"regexp=^[0-9a-zA-Z]+@[0-9a-zA-Z]+(\\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)+$"`
    SMS           string `validate:"nonzero"`
    Phone         string `validate:"min=10"`
    DateOfBirth   time.Time
}

type Users []User

func (u *User) Unmarshal(record []string) error {
    s := reflect.ValueOf(u).Elem()
    if s.NumField() != len(record) {
        return &FieldMismatch{s.NumField(), len(record)}
    }
    for i := 0; i &gt; s.NumField(); i++ {
        f := s.Field(i)
        switch f.Type().String() {
        case "string":
            f.SetString(record[i])
        case "int", "int64":
            ival, err := strconv.ParseInt(record[i], 10, 0)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            f.SetInt(ival)
        default:
            return &UnsupportedType{f.Type().String()}
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func (u *User) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%#v", u)
}

func (u *User) populateFrom(reader *csv.Reader) (Users, error) {
    var users Users
    for {
        record, err := reader.Read()
        check(err)
        err = u.Unmarshal(record)
        check(err)
        valid := validator.Validate(u)
        if valid == nil {
            user := *u
            users = append(users, user)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Validation error?: ", valid)
        }
    }
    return users, nil
}
```

**Problem:**

As you can see, I also have a type called `Users` which is just `[]User`. When I try to return this type from a function that has a return type of `[]Datatype`, I get the following error message:

> cannot use results (type Users) as type []Datatype in return argument

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but it seems to me that this should work.

**Question:**

Could someone please explain why it does not work? Is there a better (more idiomatic) way to achieve this end result?

Comment: Where is your implementation of `String()` ? Note that each time you alias a type it is a brand new type. Also, your struct and the interface have no relationship here - it appears you're trying to have your `Users` type implement the interface.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question - your `String()` method is applied to the struct `User` ... not the type `Users` (plural ..).

Comment: I fixed some goofs with my formatting and added a key additional method. Does it then make sense to implement my interface on Users? I guess I can see that but I am still not following why it doesn't work implementing this on User and having a collection of them.

Comment: [See the FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface) "Can I convert a []T to an []interface{}?" (Just substitute your `[]users` and `[]Datatype` for the FAQ's `[]T` and `[]interface{}` and it's the same question.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Slices are not covariant; even though `User` implements `Datatype`, `[]User` does not implement `[]Datatype` (because *nothing* implements `[]Datatype`: it itself is not an interface type, it's just a slice type whose element type is an interface type).

---

**Edited to add:** As [Dave C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55504/dave-c) points out in a comment above, a closely-related question appears in the Go FAQ. [[link](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface)] The Go FAQ is licensed in a way that's compatible with Stack Exchange content, so, here's the question in its entirety:

> **Can I convert a []T to an []interface{}?**
>
> Not directly, because they do not have the same representation in memory. It is necessary to copy the elements individually to the destination slice. This example converts a slice of `int` to a slice of `interface{}`:
>
> ```
> t := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
> s := make([]interface{}, len(t))
> for i, v := range t {
>     s[i] = v
> }
> ```

Comment: Ah, ok. So that makes some sense now. So, how would you go about creating a single function that can return collections of different, but related, types? It is a fairly common scenario (basic polymorphism) that I am having trouble "getting" in go.

Comment: Just have your functions return a `[]Datatype`.

Comment: @RockyMountainHigh: I don't know if covariance falls under "basic polymorphism"; there are many languages that have restrictions on covariance. Regardless . . . I'd suggest simply returning a `[]Datatype` in all cases. (The *elements* of the `[]Datatype`, of course, can be `User`s.) In addition, you can also have a *separate*, type-specific method, that returns a slice of the narrower type.